# can i get the average number of users in all groups and then return groups with more users in cypher query in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

if I wanted to find the group with the number of users more than average number of users i added the where clause, but we can't use aggregates in where....
here is my cypher query:

```
params.put("query", "name:*");
ExecutionResult result = engine.execute( "start n=node:groups({query}) 
match n<-[:Members_In]-x 
with n,count(distinct x) as numberOfUsers
where numOfUsers>avg(numOfUsers) 
return  n.name,numOfUsers ", params );
```

`n` is the group name and x is the users of each group.
how can I get the avg number of groups users and then return the groups with more users?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using WITH, like

```
start n=node(*) 
match n<-[:Members_In]-x 
with n, count(distinct x) as countOfUsers
with n, avg(countOfUsers) as avg 
where avg<3 
return  n.name, avg
```

example at http://tinyurl.com/czkpmws

Comment: in the second with when we use n with average, avg is countofusers.and this query does't work right.

Comment: For that, you would need 2 queries. We are experimenting with doing something similar to what you ask, but it's not in yet.